# Read from two files in simultaneously in bash when they may be missing trailing newlines

Tags: linux, bash

I have two text files that I'm trying to read through line by line at the same time. The files do not necessarily have the same number of lines, and the script should stop reading when it reaches the end of either file. I'd like to keep this as "pure" bash as possible. Most of the solutions I've found for doing this suggest something of the form:

```
while read -r f1 && read -r f2 <&3; do
    echo "$f1"
    echo "$f2"
done < file1 3<file2
```

However this fails if the last line of a file does not have a newline.

If I were only reading one file I would do something like:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "$line"
done < file1
```

but when I try to extend this to reading multiple files by doing things like:

```
while IFS='' read -r f1 || [[ -n "$f1" ]] && read -r f2 <&3 || [[ -n "$f2" ]]; do
    echo "$f1"
    echo "$f2"
done < file1 3<file2
```

or

```
while IFS='' read -r f1 && read -r f2 <&3 || [[ -n "$f1" || -n "$f2" ]]; do
    echo "$f1"
    echo "$f2"
done < file1 3<file2
```

I can't seem to get the logic right and the loop either doesn't terminate or finishes without reading the last line.

I can get the desired behavior using:

```
while true; do
    read -r f1 <&3 || if [[ -z "$f1" ]]; then break; fi;
    read -r f2 <&4 || if [[ -z "$f2" ]]; then break; fi;
    echo "$f1"
    echo "$f2"
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

However this doesn't seem to match the normal (?)

```
while ... read ...; do
     ... 
done
```

idiom that I see for reading files.

Is there a better way to simultaneously read from two files that might have differing numbers of lines and last lines that are not newline terminated?

What are the potential drawbacks of my way of reading the files?

Comment: Even reading a single file will fail to read last line if it doesn't end on a new line, so the problem is file format not your code I guess.

Comment: `while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do...` reads the last line fine if it doesn't have a newline.

Comment: The problem could be that files don't have the same number of lines so your first examples will all fail at some point because of the && operator.

Comment: Consider fixing the input files. POSIX text files are *required* to end with a newline, and the `read` command is designed to work with POSIX text files.

Comment: @chepner I would love to, unfortunately I don't have control over the input files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the precedence of the `&&` and `||` operators by grouping them with `{ }`:

```
while { IFS= read -r f1 || [[ -n "$f1" ]]; } && { IFS= read -r f2 <&3 || [[ -n "$f2" ]]; }; do
```

Some notes: You can't use `( )` for grouping in this case because that forces its contents to run in a subshell, and variables `read` in subshells aren't available in the parent shell. Also, you need a `;` before each `}`, so the shell can tell it isn't just a parameter to the last command. Finally, you need `IFS=` (or equivalently `IFS=''`) before *each* `read` command, since assignments given as a prefix to a command apply only to that one command.